# Media Player Filetypes

Tags: codecs, smplayer

I am using SMPlayer but it is not supporting all video formats. What should I do?

The screen remain white. The format of those videos are '720p.BluRay.2CH.x265.HEVC-PSA'.

Comment: Have you tried vlc player?

Comment: Remember to ad the extra codecs from the 'Restricted extras*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HEVC/H265 videos not playing in SM Player](/q/698152)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install VLC, which able to play many media formats.

You may install through terminal which is faster than using Ubuntu Software Center.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Make sure you have updated your repository before installing by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```